# Perl exists not working as expected

Tags: perl, if-statement, hash, exists

I'm trying to count the emails occurrences  in a file.
But it's seems that exists is not working as expected.
When i found a new email the code should print not in hash
Else it should print in hash.

But "in hash" is never printed

How can i count the email ocurrences?

```
use strict;
use 5.014;
open(FCG,"<","pruecorreos") or die "No se puede \n";
my %correos = ();
my $i = 0;
while (<FCG>) {
    chomp;
    print "\nAnalizando: $_";

    if ( my @m = $_ =~/(\w+@\w+\.\w+)(\.\w+)*/ ) {

        my $lel = join("",@m);
        print "lel es [$lel]";

        if ( exists $correos{$lel} ) {
            print "\n$lel  in hash";
            $correos{$lel}=1;
        }
        else {
            print "\n$lel NOT in hash";
            $correos{$lel}++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code never assigns to the hash.  The `%correos` doesn't magically get populated on its own, you have to assign key-value pairs,  `$correos{key} = $value;`. Then it makes sense testing whether there is a `defined` value for a given key (what `exists` does).  I can assure you that `exists` works.

Comment: @zdim: I don't follow you. The program has `$correos{$lel}=1` if `exists` is *true* and `$correos{$lel}++` if not.

Comment: @Chaos: Your regex is faulty. You need to escape the at sign `@`, and the second pair of parentheses will capture only the *last* occurrence of `\.\w+`.Are the values of `$lel` shown correctly?

Comment: Looks like the regex is attempting to match email addresses

Comment: @zdim: Oh dear. I've just woken up and haven't had my first coffee yet, but I don't get you. Either `=1` or `++` will permanently create the hash element. The idea is to check whether more than one line from the `FCG`  file handle produces the same captures from the regex.

Comment: @Borodin the `@` in the regex doesn't have to be escaped: `perl -Mstrict -wE 'my $str = q(user@test.com); my @m = $str =~ /(\w+@\w+\.\w+)/; say for @m'`

Comment: @Zaid: No, but it's dangerous advice to say that it doesn't need escaping. Had it not been followed by a backslash, whitespace, or the end of the pattern, perl would have tried to interpolate the corresponding array variable. Likewise braces `{ .. }` can often work in regex patterns without being escaped, but Perl now has a warning to tell you not to do that.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be advice. Just highlighting that it is not a reason for the regex to be "faulty"

Comment: @Zaid: I disagree. Code can be faulty while still performing as intended for the wrong reasons, just as I can have faulty brakes on my car while still being able to bring it to a halt.

Comment: You have `use strict` (which is actually redundant with `use 5.014`), but not `use warnings`. You might want to add that.

Comment: @zdim Not sure whether I understood your first comment right but `exists` doesn't check for the definedness of `value` but for the existance of `key`: `perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -E 'my %hash = (a => undef); say "YES" if (exists $hash{a});'` prints `YES` albeit the value is undef.

Comment: @Borodin Dear oh dear.  It was late here and all those coffees must had worn off.  I didn't get the point of the posted code, which you nicely explain. I didn't even see that the comment was yours (_that_ part was the cell phone effect.) Sorry to all for the noise :(  I'm removing those comments, except for the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken. If I run your code against this data file

#### pruecorreos

```
aaa@mail.example.com
aaa@mail.example.com
```

then I get this output

```
Analizando: aaa@mail.example.comlel es [aaa@mail.example.com]
aaa@mail.example.com NOT in hash
Analizando: aaa@mail.example.comlel es [aaa@mail.example.com]
aaa@mail.example.com  in hash[Finished in 0.1s]
```

which shows that duplicates are being detected correctly

However, the errors that I pointed out in my comment need to be fixed, and I would do it like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fcg, '<', 'pruecorreos' or die "No se puede: $!";

my %correos;

while ( <$fcg> ) {

    chomp;

    print "Analizando: $_\n";

    next unless my ($lel) = /( \w+ \@ \w+ (?: \. \w+ )+  )/x;

    print "lel es [$lel]\n";

    print $correos{$lel}++ ? "$lel is in hash\n" : "$lel is NOT in hash\n";

    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Analizando: aaa@mail.example.com
lel es [aaa@mail.example.com]
aaa@mail.example.com is NOT in hash

Analizando: aaa@mail.example.com
lel es [aaa@mail.example.com]
aaa@mail.example.com is in hash
```

Comment: Did you have your coffee yet?

Comment: @simbabque: Ah! Thanks for the reminder. There's a jug of it waiting in the kitchen. I shall be razor sharp for the next few hours!

Comment: I'm more of the tea guy in the morning. But I'm running low. Need to hurry to go buy more before I need a visa to go there...

Comment: @simbabque: You talking about England here? It wouldn't be impossible for me to ship something to you.

Comment: thanks for the offer, but the shipping is higher than buying online. I have used britishcornershop.co.uk before. They have very fair shipping if you buy a lot of stuff. Five shoe boxes of Yorkshire tea and a six pack of Irn Bru and I'm set for a while. Or I should just come visit again finally. But for the amount of things I usually buy I need to drive there. Taking a stack of charity shop books and tea on the plane is tricky. ;-)

Comment: @simbabque The TV advertisements are the best part of Irn-Bru. The soda itself will burn a hole through your stomach ;-)

Comment: @MattJacob I don't know those. I just remember this glowing liquid that tastes like mouthwash. I think in the US it's called Listerine, isn't it? :P